# How to convert R package and dependencies to debian packages?

Tags: r

I need to install R packages in several nodes (10+) in AWS.
I wont be able to open R shell in each and do install.packages("foo")

This will be done using a configuration management tool like Puppet and it'll be easier if i can do an apt-get installation of R packages automatically.

I found a list of R debian packages here:
http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/lucid/

But it does not contain all the packages that i need.

Is there a way to convert any R package and it's internal dependencies to a Debian package similar to the approach used in creating r-cran-*.deb?

Comment: My answer isn't exactly what you're looking for, but you might be able to call R CMD .. like commands from puppet

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://debian-r.debian.net/ ?

All CRAN (and many other) packages already packaged

Comment: I can't seem to reach this site today, is it gone permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages without starting the R console.  You can download the tar.gz packages from the cran website.  For example here is the tar.gz for the randomForest package: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/randomForest_4.6-7.tar.gz

R CMD INSTALL ${package}.tar.gz

Comment: For the puppet syntax, check http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/exec-a-command-in-a-manifest.html.
The following may also be relevant: https://gist.github.com/blever/7994730.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd sweet find with that gist

Answer (score -1):

The [cran2deb](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/cran2deb/) project claims to do exactly this, turning an R package into a Debian package and noting the correct dependencies.

I haven't used it myself yet.